# Hosting a MERN application with Vercel in 2021 (without Next.js)

Tags: reactjs, express, serverless, mern, vercel

I've been using Vercel to host several React web applications and it's been great! Recently, I upgraded an existing project with a backend (Express.js and MongoDB Atlas) and I'd like to host it there as well.

On my machine, the MongoDB server and all the CRUD routes are running smoothly on localhost:5000, but I'd like to know how to add this to the Vercel deployment. Vercel's documentation focuses on serverless deployment, and while I don't mind rewriting my backend if I have to, I'm wondering if there's an easier solution for adding a server/database.

The MERN stack is still relatively popular so I imagine a lot of developers have found a way to host this kind of project. If anyone can help, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Provide your code structure. i.e., where your server.js file and client located? i deployed MERN to vercel without next.js.

Comment: Sure! In the main project directory there is a folder for backend (models, routes, server.js) and another folder for src (pages, components, etc). Both folders are at the same level. 

Is that helpful?

Comment: I'll post the solution in few minutes

Comment: That would be amazing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*according to your comment your file structure should be look like this*

```
// + refer as close folder
// - refer as open folder
// > refer as file

main

  - backend
    + models
    + routes
    > package.json
    > package-lock.json
    > server.js

  - frontend
    + public
    - src
      + pages
      + components
    > package.json
    > package-lock.json
```

**step1 - edit frontend package.json**
*add homepage*

```
{
  // initially add link whatever you suppose to be link of your site
  // then after deploying to vercel, you get the exact link
  // then replace it with vercel link in "homepage" key

  "homepage": "https://awesome-app.vercel.app",
  "name": "awesome-app",
  "version": "1.0.0,
  "private": true,
  ...rest of your frontend package.json file
}
```

**step2 - add basename**

```
// you wrapped your app with either BrowserRouter or HashRouter
// add basename prop so it refer to your package.json homepage
// if your route are '/awesome-route' then is converted to
// https://awesome-app.vercel.app/awesome-route

<BrowserRouter basename='/'>    // or HashRouter
  <Switch>
    ...your routes
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**step3 - build your react**

> you have to build your frontend everytime before deployment if and only if your change your frontend code

*then your frontend should look like below*

```
  - frontend
    + build    // build folder at root of your frontend
    + public
    - src
      + pages
      + components
    > package.json
    > package-lock.json
```

**step4 - change your server.js file**
*should look like this*

```
// i use "dotenv" package
// in your case must be located at "main > backend > .env"
// see the final file structure at bottom if you don't understand

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname+'/.env'});
}

const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(process.env.mongoURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,

  // remove poolSize or set according to your need
  // read docs before setting poolSize
  // default to 5
  poolSize: 1
})
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(port);
  })

// all your routes should go here
app.use('/some-route', require(path.join(__dirname, 'api', 'routes', 'route.js'));

// static files (build of your frontend)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend', 'build')));
  app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend', 'build', 'index.html'));
  })
}
```

**step5 - add vercel.json**
*at root level of your repository i.e., in your case `main` directory*

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./backend/server.js",  // path to your server.js file
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    },
    {
      "src": "./frontend/build",    // path to your build folder
      "use": "@vercel/static"
    }
  ],

  // rewrites any request to api call with server.js
  // now your "app.use('/some-route')" would work as normal as localhost
  // no need to change your codes to serverless way

  // also remember here "/(.*)" is not regular js regex
  // it follows path-to-regex
  // playground link: https://regexr.com

  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/backend/server.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

**finally your file structure look like this**

```
// + refer as close folder
// - refer as open folder
// > refer as file

main

  - backend
    + models
    - routes
      > route.js
    > package.json
    > package-lock.json
    > .env
    > server.js

  - frontend
    - build
      + static
      > manifest.json
      > index.html
    + public
    + src
    > package.json
    > package-lock.json

  > vercel.json   // in your main directory's root
```

**the disadvantage of this method is that your have to build your frontend every time you push your repo to github**

> **remember to build your frontend before you push your repo to github if and only if you change your frontend code**

> **also remember to replace your homepage url in your frontend package.json file after deployment with vercel provided url or your custom domain url**

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: I noticed that i added `poolSize` in mongoose connect function. remove it or set according to your need.

Comment: I have deployed a MERN app following your instructions above however it wasn't deployed correctly. The deployed app is blank and shows a console log error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Here is my code: https://github.com/denskiz/emaily

And here is my deployed app: https://emaily-three.vercel.app/

Comment: I'll check it out and revert back to you soon

Comment: That would be amazing! Thanks

Comment: Right now I'm getting a Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: I'll look and revert. I'm free on weekends only.

Comment: hey @denskiz, i looked at your codes and can't figure out what's problem with your deployment. **just a tip:** add your production keys file in gitignore.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the following in your backend app.js or server.js for the frontend to load on vercelapp/

```html
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../frontend/build")));

app.get("*", function(_, res) {
    res.sendFile(
        path.join(__dirname, "../frontend/build/index.html"),
        function (err) {
            if(err) {
                res.status(500).send(err)
            }
        }
    )
})
```

Since we are making a rewrite rule: /(.*) vercel will pass all requests through the backend server.js file
This snippet will ensure that it sends the build/index.html

Sorry for bad english!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This repo is setup for MERN stack vercel deployment. I was able to adapt a MERN app and successfully deploy by forking this repo https://github.com/hack4impact-uiuc/mern-template/tree/main/client/src and updating.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33137543)